# How to make up a column with select in sql

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to make up a temporary table for debugging purpose. I got to

```sql
select array[1, 2] as a, 2 as b;
   a    | b 
--------+---
 [1, 2] | 2
```

How could I make up another row, e.g.

```
   a    | b 
--------+---
 [1, 2] | 2 
--------+---
 [3, 4] | 5
```

The above results will be used in `WITH tmp AS (...)` for further experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `union all`:

```
select array[1, 2] as a, 2 as b
union all
select array[3, 4] as a, 5 as b
```

If your database supports both arrays and `values`, you can do:

```
select v.*
from (values (array[1, 2], 2), (array[3, 4], 5)
     ) v(a, b);
```

Comment: I like the second approach, is there an even easier way?

Comment: @zyxue in the `WITH tmp AS` (per your question) clause you need only `VALUES`, so the shortest version is: `WITH tmp(a, b) AS (VALUES (array[1, 2], 2), (array[3, 4], 5)) SELECT * FROM tmp;`